# How to modify data such that it is sorted per date and orders?

Tags: python, pandas

How to modify the data set such that it shows per month for each country how many purchases were made?

[image]

This is part of the dataset I have. There are hundreds of orders per date per country. I would like to modify the data set such that it shows per month for each country how many purchases were made.

I am beginner in data science, any help will be highly appreciated.

So far I have sorted the countries which I would like to use in my report.

```
 datasetCountry = dataset[dataset['Country'].isin(["France","Belgium","EIRE","Germany","Netherlands","Norway","Portugal","Spain","Switzerland"])].copy()
 datasetCountry.head()
```

But I do not have an idea how to count the orders per month for each of them

Comment: Please provide a copyable [mcve].

Comment: So you want to *group* your data by date and country and count the entries? That's a [Group-by problem](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/groupby.html).

Comment: Change the format of the invoice date to Y-M, then `datasetCountry.groupby(['InvoiceDate', 'Country'])['Quantity'].sum()` should work, note `count()` and `sum()` will return different values. `count()` will return the number of times quantity is seen for a country and `sum()` will add the values in this column.

Comment: `how many purchases were made` is ambiguous. Does that mean how many orders/invoices or sum of quantity?

Comment: @jpp  ->  i.e. how many invoices were created

Comment: @Dakata, Then you need `groupby` with `nunique` on `InvoiceNo`.

Comment: But how can I group them per month per country, because many of the orders were made in the same day?

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.to_datetime(['2012-02-08', '2012-02-20']),
                   'Orders': [5, 10]})

    # normalize day to beginning of month
    df['NewMonth'] = df['Date'] + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)  #update here
    df['NewMonth'] = df['Date'] - pd.to_timedelta(df['Date'].dt.day-1, unit='D')

    #group by month
    new = df.groupby('NewMonth')  #output
    summary = new['Orders'].sum()

Comment: @Maria Nazari example?

Comment: @Dakata i provided an example in my comment, since your question is labeled as duplicated I can't post an answer. Paste by comment and separate by comments

Comment: useful link https://www.shanelynn.ie/summarising-aggregation-and-grouping-data-in-python-pandas/

Comment: the last line is this -> new['Orders'].sum() <- ?

Comment: summary = new['Orders'].sum()